# Array of shapes - Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

I've created some Shapes with SwiftUI which I want to save in an array so I can loop over them and show them in a View. 
`let diceShapes: [Shape] = [Triangle(), Pentagon(), ....]`

However, I get an error message when saving the array **Protocol 'Shape' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements** .

Shape don't have any associated types itself but Shape conforms to View and Animatable which both have one associated type so I guess that is the problem!? I thought about adding a struct or something similar which conforms to Shape but I can't get it to work. It don't has to be an array, I have the same problem with functions which should return Shape-like. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them into `AnyView` type eraser, like

```
let diceShapes: [AnyView] = [AnyView(Triangle()), AnyView(Pentagon()), ....]
```